# Problem with ms-thumb-frame-selected class in Master Slider

Tags: loop, css

I'm using [Master Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/) to provide a slideshow.

Inside a loop I've put some CSS to make the class `.ms-thumb-frame-selected` to dynamically use the thumb of a post as background. But now my problem is that all elements with `.ms-thumb-frame` class get the same image. But when I check from "Inspect element" in my browser I can see that the other images are correct.

Here's my code:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6&cat=');
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
$bg= 0;
$slider_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');

?>
<?php
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
if($bg == 0){ ?>

    <style>
        #masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected
        {
            background:linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)), url("<?php echo $url;?>") no-repeat ;
            background-size:cover;
            opacity: .8;
            background-position: 100 0;
            transition: background .5s;
        }
    </style>
```

and this is loop

```
<!-- new slide -->
<div class="ms-slide">
    <!-- slide background -->
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/masterslider/blank.gif" data-src="<?php echo $slider_image[0];?> " alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
    <!-- slide text layer -->
    <div class="ms-layer ms-caption"  data-offset-x      = "10"
 data-offset-y      = "15"
 data-origin        = "tr"
 data-type          = "text"
 data-effect        = "bottom(90)"
 data-duration      = "900"
 data-ease          = "easeOutQuart">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?> </a></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- slide text title it shows in thumbnail list. -->

    <div class="ms-thumb">
        <div class="ms-thumb-text">
            <h3><?php //the_title();?>
                <?php  if ( get_the_title() ) {
                    $t = get_the_title();
                    $t =  mb_substr($t, 0, 102, 'UTF-8');

                    }else{
                        the_ID();
                    }
                    echo $t;
                ?>
            </h3>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php }?>
<!-- end of slide -->
```

and this is javascript

```
t.slideAction = function (t) {
        var r = n(t.$element.find(".ms-thumb"))
            , u = this
            , i = n("<div><\/div>").addClass("ms-thumb-frame").append(r).append(n('<div class="ms-thumb-ol"><\/div>')).bind("click", function () {
                u.changeSlide(i)
            });
        if (i[0].index = this.index_count++, this.$thumbscont.append(i), n.browser.msie) r.on("dragstart", function (n) {
            n.preventDefault()
        });
```

After looking at my slideshow I found all background images are the same but if check the code in my browser via "Inspect element" it get other image. How's this possible?

Comment: Please add the resulting inspected code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are simply overwriting `#masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected` with each loop. So in the end only the last iteration will take effect.

You maybe need to add the post ID as class somewhere as well and then target `#masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected .post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> {  }` in your CSS.

---

Adjust your markup **inside The Loop** to print the post ID as class on the same element/`<div>` you are targeting with `#masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected`. So that in the end you can use `#masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected.my-post-id-class-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>`.

So asuming your markup **inside The Loop** was:

```
<div id="masterslider">
    <div class=".ms-thumb-frame-selected">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now make it:

```
<div id="masterslider">
    <div class="ms-thumb-frame-selected post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS should be:

```
#masterslider .ms-thumb-frame-selected.post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> {
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)), url("<?php echo $url; ?>") no-repeat ;
    background-position: 100 0;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: .8;
    transition: background .5s;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more , and thanks for edit my question

Comment: can help me and explain more

Comment: @ẪĦmẻḓMøĦẫmẻḓ – Answer updated.

Comment: i add my loop and javascript i try it with your code not work :(

Comment: can you help with my loop @leymannx

Comment: @ẪĦmẻḓMøĦẫmẻḓ – What exactly is unclear about my answer? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: only loop is i edit in post look to it that problem and javascript insert the div so i can edit loop like that please see my edit for post